# Как обработать событие добавления бота в канал/группу?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Нужно чтобы после добавления бота в какой либо канал/чат бот получил ID этого чата. Не знаю, какой хендлер использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно легко реализовать с помощью **telebot**

```
import telebot 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен")   

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Чат: {id}")    
 
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

**Если ответ помог, то не забудь поставить галочку**

Comment: Да, но это решение для обработки сообщения из канала, а мне нужно моментальное уведомление о добавлении бота в канал.